# Concurrency issue with MySQL select for update?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, concurrency

We have been using MySQL for quite sometime `(Server version: 5.6.10 MySQL Community Server)` with Hibernate as ORM and Spring for transaction management.

We use pessimistic locking at a number of places. But today while debugging a concurrency issue, I found a strange issue. If two threads try to acquire a pessimistic lock on a row at the same instant, they are both able to get it. Here is the DAO method that acquires the lock:

```
@Override
public PurchaseOrder lockOnPurchaseOrder(Integer purchaseOrderId) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select p from PurchaseOrder p where p.id = :purchaseOrderId);
    query.setParameter("purchaseOrderId", purchaseOrderId);
    query.setLockMode("p", LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    return (PurchaseOrder) query.uniqueResult();
}
```

Here is the code snippet from the service that is using it:

```
@Override
public void doService(int purchaseOrderId) {
    purchaseService.lockOnPurchaseOrder(purchaseOrderId);  // Problematic line

    // If lock is acquired, so something

}
```

Then I tested that if one thread acquires the lock, and then other thread tries to acquire it a moment later, it blocks on this call. So this is working fine.

But if two threads simultaneously execute the problematic line, they both get the lock. I checked the mysql logs by turning on general logs, two `select for update` statements are getting executed.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: did you have any problems locking? like exception being thrown? can you post your logs here please

Comment: No there was no problem, its just that if two threads execute the 'lockOnPurchaseOrder' call at the same time, both the calls return, i.e. both the threads have access to the lock. Checked the mysql general logs, two select for update statements are getting executed.